# RecyclerView Header or top view

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

Please Help me!

How to add View at top of RecyclerView.

This image: https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/pagination-4-recyclerview-multiple-viewtypes-header.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pattern"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_image_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/line" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_swipe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: you want your top image scroll as well as your recyclerview or it's always be there

Comment: I want top image scroll as well as my recyclerview

Comment: just use the header for that top image to that recyclerview is done, easy and simple!

Comment: you can search the internet on how to add header to your recyclerview or i can help you here though by implement some sample if you want

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow.

I feel like it is hard to understand your question. From my perspective you want to add another image over (on top) of the recyclerview. Respectivle you do not need the NestedScrollView. Please try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pattern"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_image_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/line" />
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivNew1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/line" />
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivNew2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/line" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If this is not the answer to your question please let me know! I could also be possible that you want to add another Image in the Recyclerview. Than it would be very helpful if you could post your layout.xml file.

Nice Regards

Comment: No Mr. Christian.gruener

Comment: I can't add View at top of Recyclerview. View can't scroll with RecyclerView :(

Comment: You do not need a nestedScrollView when you use the Recyclerview. Let me update my post. This should work write now. If you are happy with my answer It would be great if you could use the check to accept it.

Comment: Mr. Christian.gruener I need this

Comment: Is it working or not? Please elaborate your problem more clearly. Normally the updated code should work for you!

Comment: If you can not scroll with your recyclerview than you probably inflate the recyclerview wrongly. Please post your Adapter and where you inflate it into your post.

Comment: If the answer is working for you now, please accept my answer :)!

Comment: @Christian.gruener he want to scroll the recyclerview as well as that image, so as your answer the image won't scroll that's why he's not accept it